# Android Peer-to-Peer technolog

Tags: android, google-tv

Now that we've got a smartphone, tablet, GoogleTV, connected watches and Google classes soon, the need for Android Peer-to-Peer technology is rising. What is your opinion on connecting devices?

Do I need to focus on framewworks like MOVL and AllJoyn, or write my own custom framework?

Comment: where do you get that @W.Elsinga,.... MOVL ? Neverheard....

Answer (score 2):

It is public knowledge that Google/YouTube is working on using the DIAL protocol for network device discovery and for launching apps on networked devices.

My own testing shows that there is a DIAL server on each Google TV device. But using the documentation on dial-multiscreen.org I have only been able to get the discovery part of the protocol working. Meaning I can find all the DIAL servers on the network, but I haven't been able to launch or control any apps on those devices. Looking at the packets on the network when the YouTube mobile app "flings" videos to a Google TV device, I can see that the discovery part is used too. But then there are other TCP traffic which is not documented, which is likely how the YouTube app makes videos play on Google TV devices. So it looks like the DIAL stuff is work in progress for Google and the dial-multiscreen.org site is mostly for developers to get ready to develop second-screen apps using the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Found a the Google training class on *Network Service Discovery* and *WiFi Direct*.

http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think DIAL sounds very promising, as it seems to be supported by many big companies already. I hope Google will integrate it directly into Android, so that Intents can be directly mapped to DIAL commands and f.e. the app-Picker for a Action_VIEW-intent could directly offer DIAL compatible devices. And of course they will have to make Anymote use DIAL too. I really hope to see something like this at I/O and in KeyLimePie.

But as long nothing of this is reality, i think ANI (https://github.com/pocmo/Android-Network-Intents) are worth a look.